# XWalk (Crosswalk) CookieManager crashes app in NDK

Tags: android, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I'm doing the following:

- In my `Launcher` activity, after `onCreate` i'm initializing the default `CookieManager` like so:

  ```
  CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ctx);
  }

  cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
  cookieManager.setAcceptFileSchemeCookies(true);
  ```
- After that I'm doing this...

  ```
  CookieHandler.setDefault(new WebkitCookieManagerProxy());
  ```
- ...where I'm extending the `CookieManager` and doing this:

  ```
  public class WebkitCookieManagerProxy extends CookieManager {
  private static final String TAG = WebkitCookieManagerProxy.class.getName();
  private XWalkCookieManager crosswalkCookieManager;

  public WebkitCookieManagerProxy() {
      this(null, null);
  }

  /* package */ WebkitCookieManagerProxy(CookieStore store, CookiePolicy cookiePolicy) {
      super(null, cookiePolicy);

      this.crosswalkCookieManager = new XWalkCookieManager();

  }

  // java.net.CookieManager overrides

  @Override
  public void put(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) throws IOException {
      // make sure our args are valid
      if ((uri == null) || (responseHeaders == null)) return;

      // save our url once
      String url = uri.toString();

      // go over the headers
      for (String headerKey : responseHeaders.keySet()) {
          // ignore headers which aren't cookie related
          if ((headerKey == null) || !(headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie2") || headerKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Set-Cookie")))
              continue;

          // process each of the headers
          for (String headerValue : responseHeaders.get(headerKey)) {
              this.crosswalkCookieManager.setCookie(url, headerValue);
          }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public Map<String, List<String>> get(URI uri, Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders) throws IOException {
      // make sure our args are valid
      if ((uri == null) || (requestHeaders == null))
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is null");

      // save our url once
      String url = uri.toString();

      // prepare our response
      Map<String, List<String>> res = new java.util.HashMap<String, List<String>>();

      // get the cookie
      String cookie = null;
      if (this.crosswalkCookieManager.hasCookies()) {
          cookie = this.crosswalkCookieManager.getCookie(url);
      }

      // return it
      if (cookie != null) {
          res.put("Cookie", Arrays.asList(cookie));
      }
      return res;
  }

  @Override
  public CookieStore getCookieStore() {
      // we don't want anyone to work with this cookie store directly
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
  ```

  }

**My problem** is that when it enters the `put()` method above, it crashes with an exception. Any calls on the manager crashes the app, for example calling `hasCookies()` or `getCookies()`

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hei Peter. No, I don't recall ever solving this. We ended up not using XWalk, we had an implementation with flavors and we ended up using the native Webview because xwalk was just not that stable for the things we wanted to use it for. I think i opened an issue on their jira thing ... but I haven't followed the thread, so no clue if they reported it as a bug or if they fixed whatever it was that was wrong .... Sorry, I can't be of much help. :( Good luck tho'.